# How to add footers to a text output in a XSLT transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have a requirement with xml file: I need to add footer to a text output. But i'm a new guys in XSLT, please help me.

Input Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
   <TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY>
      <ERPORDERLINENUM>1.0000000000000000</ERPORDERLINENUM>
      <ERPORDERLINE>1000-000001</ERPORDERLINE>
      <SKU>24867B43</SKU>
      <STOREID />
      <WAREHOUSE>W3501</WAREHOUSE>
   </TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY>
   <TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY>
      <ERPORDERLINENUM>2.0000000000000000</ERPORDERLINENUM>
      <ERPORDERLINE>1000-000001</ERPORDERLINE>
      <SKU>483055</SKU>
      <STOREID />
      <WAREHOUSE>W3501</WAREHOUSE>
   </TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY>
   <TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY>
      <ERPORDERLINENUM>1.0000000000000000</ERPORDERLINENUM>
      <ERPORDERLINE>1000-000002</ERPORDERLINE>
      <SKU>24867B43</SKU>
      <STOREID />
      <WAREHOUSE>W3501</WAREHOUSE>
   </TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY>
   <TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY>
      <ERPORDERLINENUM>2.0000000000000000</ERPORDERLINENUM>
      <ERPORDERLINE>1000-000002</ERPORDERLINE>
      <SKU>483055</SKU>
      <STOREID />
      <WAREHOUSE>W3501</WAREHOUSE>
   </TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY>
   <TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY>
      <ERPORDERLINENUM>3.0000000000000000</ERPORDERLINENUM>
      <ERPORDERLINE>1000-000002</ERPORDERLINE>
      <SKU>483055</SKU>
      <STOREID />
      <WAREHOUSE>W3501</WAREHOUSE>
   </TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY>
</Document>
```

Output:

```
HEADER|24867B43|1.0000000000000000
1000-000001|W3501
1000-000001|1.0000000000000000|24867B43
1000-000001|2.0000000000000000|483055
1000-000002|W3501
1000-000002|1.0000000000000000|24867B43
1000-000002|2.0000000000000000|483055
1000-000002|3.0000000000000000|483055
FOOTER|24867B43|1.0000000000000000
```

my xslt:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="text"/>
   
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>HEADER</xsl:text>
     <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="Document/TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY/SKU"/>
     <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="Document/TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY/ERPORDERLINENUM"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
   <xsl:key name="keyAssessmentID" match="TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY" use="ERPORDERLINE"/>
   <xsl:template match="/*">
       <Document>
         <xsl:for-each select=".//TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('keyAssessmentID',ERPORDERLINE)[1])]">
            <xsl:variable name="ERPORDERLINE" select="ERPORDERLINE"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="ERPORDERLINE"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="WAREHOUSE"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('keyAssessmentID', $ERPORDERLINE)"/>
         </xsl:for-each>
         </Document>
  </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY">
         <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="ERPORDERLINE"/>
         <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="ERPORDERLINENUM"/>
         <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="SKU"/>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template match="TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY/*">
       <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    
  </xsl:copy>
  
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't know how to add fix text and a element value to the end of output like the requirement.
I can add on the header, but with footer. can't find a way to do that.
Please help me, thanks you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your main template to

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>HEADER</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Document/TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY/SKU"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Document/TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY/ERPORDERLINENUM"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    <!-- Here comes the footer -->
    <xsl:text>&#10;FOOTER</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Document/TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY[3]/SKU"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Document/TRU_TRANSFERORDERENTITY[3]/ERPORDERLINENUM"/>        
</xsl:template>
```

Now, you add a footer to the output. Of course, I did only include sample data in the `select` expression, according to your sample output.

Output is:

```
HEADER|24867B43|1.0000000000000000
1000-000001|W3501
1000-000001|1.0000000000000000|24867B43
1000-000001|2.0000000000000000|483055
1000-000002|W3501
1000-000002|1.0000000000000000|24867B43
1000-000002|2.0000000000000000|483055
1000-000002|3.0000000000000000|483055
FOOTER|24867B43|1.0000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the template with `match="/"` where you output your "header" information, add any information you want to output as the "footer" at the end of the template, after the last element you currently have in there.